# What is the best way to update a JavaFX2 gui for high speed operations?

Tags: javafx-2

I have an application that is talking to a hardware device over serial.  This device is sending a json object every 30ms.  This json object is the devices "state" its a motion controller.

Basically the messages look like this:

```
{"sr":{"line":2524,"posx":1.000,"posy":21.000,"posz":20.000,"posa":11.459,"feed":0.000,"vel":0.000,"unit":1,"coor":1,"dist":0,"frmo":0,"momo":0,"stat":2}}
```

I get these 1x every 30ms.  I have to parse them.  Then "draw" them onto the JavaFX gui.

Here is how I am parsing:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                //We are now back in the EventThread and can update the GUI
                try {
                    JsonRootNode json = JDOM.parse(l);

                    xAxisVal.setText(json.getNode("sr").getNode("posx").getText());
                    yAxisVal.setText(json.getNode("sr").getNode("posy").getText());
                    zAxisVal.setText(json.getNode("sr").getNode("posz").getText());
                    aAxisVal.setText(json.getNode("sr").getNode("posa").getText());
                    drawLine();

                } catch (argo.saj.InvalidSyntaxException ex) {
                    //Json line invalid.
                }
            }
        });
```

And here is the draw code I am using:

```
public void drawLine() {
    xl.setX(Float.parseFloat(xAxisVal.getText()) + 400);
    y1.setY(Float.parseFloat(yAxisVal.getText()) + 400);
    LineTo tmpL = new LineTo((Float.parseFloat(xAxisVal.getText()) * 2) + 400, (Float.parseFloat(yAxisVal.getText()) * 2) + 400);
    path.getElements().add(tmpL);

}
```

So basically I am creating a runnable object every 30ms then parsing and drawing.  Is this the best way to do this?  You can see a video of it in action:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhBB3QcmHOg&feature=youtu.be

But it seems like its "jerky" and pretty resource hungry.  I am hoping for someone to give me suggestions on how to optimize this code?  Perhaps point out something I am missing?

*As an FYI the motion controller board we are making is called TinyG.  Its opensource hardware.

More info is here:
http://www.synthetos.com/wiki/index.php?title=Projects:TinyG*

*Firmware here:
https://github.com/synthetos/TinyG*

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you may want to profile your app with Netbeans Profiler or with Eclipse's [tptp plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/), and find out who is hogging the resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems to perform too much calculations on event queue which blocks graphic rendering while your data is being parsed. You should make calculations in separate thread and call `Platform.runLater()` only for relevant ui code:

```
    try {

        JsonRootNode json = JDOM.parse(l);
        final String xVal = json.getNode("sr").getNode("posx").getText();
        final String yVal = json.getNode("sr").getNode("posy").getText();
        final String zVal = json.getNode("sr").getNode("posz").getText();
        final String aVal = json.getNode("sr").getNode("posa").getText();

        // here you are calling UI getter, and parse it each time
        // it would be more optimal to store `x` value in separate variable
        // between updates
        final float x = Float.parseFloat(xAxisVal.getText());
        final float y = Float.parseFloat(yAxisVal.getText());

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                //We are now back in the EventThread and can update the GUI
                try {

                    xAxisVal.setText(xVal);
                    yAxisVal.setText(yVal);
                    zAxisVal.setText(zVal);
                    aAxisVal.setText(aVal);
                    xl.setX(x + 400);
                    y1.setY(y + 400);
                    LineTo tmpL = new LineTo(x * 2 + 400, y * 2 + 400);
                    path.getElements().add(tmpL);

                }
            }
        }

    } catch (argo.saj.InvalidSyntaxException ex) {
        //Json line invalid.
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the `xAxisVal.getText()` and `yAxisVal.getText()` calls should be made off the JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: You right, but it works in most cases. Anyway they shouldn't be called at all as stated in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already, try the [developer preview release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html).  There were some modifications on the JavaFX 2.1 preview branch to [smooth animation and rendering performance](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-13660) and optimize [path logic](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10065174).

Alternative approaches would be to write to a HTML5 canvas in a WebView or make use of a [JavaFX canvas node](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17407) once one is available in JavaFX 2.2.